# Need Explaination to Xerosploit's Sniffer Function code

Tags: sniffer, sniffing

I'm looking at the sourcecode of [Xerosploit](https://github.com/LionSec/xerosploit/blob/master/xerosploit.py), and there is a piece of code I don't understand:

```
cmd_snif = os.system("xettercap " + target_parse + target_ips + "
    -P MYSQL, SNPP, DHCP, WHATSAPP, RLOGIN, IRC, HTTPS, POST, PGSQL, NNTP, DICT, HTTPAUTH, TEAMVIEWER, MAIL, SNMP, MPD, COOKIE, NTLMSS, FTP, REDIS
    -I " + up_interface + " --gateway " + gateway + " -O,
    --log /opt/xerosploit/xerosniff/" + filename + ".log
    --sniffer-output /opt/xerosploit/xerosniff/" + filename + ".pcap")
```

What exactly is `xettercap`? What do the options of `-P` (i.e. "MYSQL, SNPP, DHCP, ...") do? What do they refer to in the sniff logs?

Which options should I use if I want to see just the *important* things, such as POST data (usernames, passwords, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xettercap` is [part of xerosploit](https://github.com/LionSec/xerosploit/blob/master/tools/bettercap/bin/xettercap) and a wrapper around the now legacy ruby implementation of [`bettercap`](https://www.bettercap.org/legacy/).

As such, all the options are just passed down to bettercap. Here is a quick rundown of the options you asked for:

> `-P, --parsers PARSERS`
>
> Comma separated list of packet parsers to enable, `*` for all ( NOTE: will enable the sniffer ), available:
>
> - COOKIE
> - CREDITCARD
> - DHCP
> - DICT
> - FTP
> - HTTPAUTH
> - HTTPS
> - IRC
> - MAIL
> - MPD
> - MYSQL
> - NTLMSS
> - PGSQL
> - POST
> - REDIS
> - RLOGIN
> - SNMP
> - SNPP
> - URL
> - WHATSAPP
>
> Default is `*` (enable all)

As for which options to choose if you want to see "important" things depends on what you define as important. You specifically mentioned post data, so I recommend using `-P POST` at least. The documentation mentioned that enabling all parsers is the default, so I think you can't go wrong with that.

Comment: Xettercap can run on windows as well right? As long as windows has Ruby support

Comment: The documentation as linked in the answer states: "Moreover, it is fully compatible with GNU/Linux, Mac OS X and OpenBSD platforms." They don't mention support for Windows, so I doubt that it would work without putting serious effort in. Then again, you can download VM software free for personal use, together with Kali Linux. I see no reason to pentest on windows unless you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: I really need to sniff using Windows for some reasons what can i do?

Comment: I think this is out-of-scope for this question. I would suggest you to create a new question like "Can Xerosploit run on Windows?"